# iOS: Code signature invalid/required code signature missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm currently working on an iOS tweak called "LockWatch" that is supposed to display watchOS-like watch faces on the lock screen. This tweak involves a basic plugin system that loads a bundle (name.watchface) from a specified directory, which is working so far.

The problem is, however, that these bundles cannot be executed on a device due to either a missing or an invalid code signature, but inside the iOS Simulator, the bundles are loaded and executed just fine.

I had this working on iOS 9 by adding the "com.apple.backboard.client" entitlement (because the logs said that this particular entitlement was missing and therefore SpringBoard was crashing).

The bundle project itself is a simple Xcode project created with a "Bundle" target from the macOS tab, the Base SDK is set to "Latest iOS (10.2)".

I've tried the following signing methods:

- Not signing at all
- Xcode-managed signing
- Xcode manual signing (for both Debug and Release)
- Signing with ldid without entitlements
- Signing with ldid with entitlements

The logs changed between these two texts:

```
SpringBoard(CoreFoundation)[PID] <Notice>: Error loading /var/mobile/Library/LockWatch/Watch Faces/prototype.watchface/prototype:  dlopen(/var/mobile/Library/LockWatch/Watch Faces/prototype.watchface/prototype, 265): no suitable image found. Did Find:
/var/mobile/Library/LockWatch/Watch Faces/prototype.watchface/prototype: required code signature missing for '/var/mobile/Library/LockWatch/Watch Faces/prototype.watchface/prototype'

SpringBoard(CoreFoundation)[PID] <Notice>: Error loading /var/mobile/Library/LockWatch/Watch Faces/prototype.watchface/prototype:  dlopen(/var/mobile/Library/LockWatch/Watch Faces/prototype.watchface/prototype, 265): no suitable image found. Did Find:
/var/mobile/Library/LockWatch/Watch Faces/prototype.watchface/prototype: code signature invalid for '/var/mobile/Library/LockWatch/Watch Faces/prototype.watchface/prototype'
```

Because the binary cannot be executed, its principal class instance cannot be added to an array and SpringBoard crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I finally solved it myself.

As it turns out, the watch face bundles haven't been signed at all (hence the `required code signature missing` message).

I added a `Run Script` phase to the bundles containing the following script:

`/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none $CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH/$PRODUCT_NAME`

I got the idea when I was researching a different issue about code signing where someone suggested to clear the contents of the _CodeSignature folder. Which was apparently non-existent in my build output.